# i have this import that isnt working and coems up with error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, import

```
import pygame
import maze_game
from ...OOP_way_options import Menu as Main_Menu
from pyvidplayer2 import Video

SCREEN = None
clock = None
vid = None
video_length = None

def run_main_menu():
    global SCREEN, clock, vid, video_length
    
    pygame.init()
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Provide video class with the path to your video
    vid = Video("assets/background_main.mp4")
    video_length = vid.duration
    main_menu()
```

the file layout looks like this:

```
COMP SCI COURSEWORK/
    __init__.py
    GAMES/
        __init__.py
        Maze_Game/
            __init__.py
            maze_main.py
        OOP_way_options.py
```

This is the error that is coming up:

```
  File "e:\Programming\Howard\COMP SCI COURSEWORK\GAMES\Maze_Game\maze_main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ... import OOP_way_options
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I tried

```
import sys
import os

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, os.pardir))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)

from ...OOP_way_options import Menu as OOP_menu
```

but it hadn't worked

Comment: Where is the main script located with which you start the program?